# CodeIgniter: Loosing my POST variables in login form

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, http-post

I have an login form as view in CodeIgniter:

```
<?php 

            echo '$_POST<hr>';
            var_dump($_POST);
?>

<?php echo '<h3>'. $message . '</h3>'?>
<span style="color: red;"><?php echo validation_errors(); ?></span>

<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/admin/auth/index" name="login_form" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    Email: <input name="user_email" id="user_email" value="" />
    <br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="user_password" id="user_password" value="" />
<br>
    <input type="submit" name="login_submit" id="login_submit" />
</form>
```

The controller resides in /application/controllers/admin

When submitted, the post variables are lost and empty in my CodeIgniter controller.

```
<?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

            echo '$_POST<hr>';
            var_dump($_POST);
?>

<form action="https://www.example.com.com/dashboard/login_test.php" name="login_form" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    Email: <input name="user_email" id="user_email" value="" />
    <br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="user_password" id="user_password" value="" />
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="login_submit" id="login_submit" />
</form>
```

However, if I put the following form in /dashboard/ besides the CodeIgniter installation, I receive all my POST variables. Interestingly, this happens on a remote AWS EC2 instances, while locally, on a MAMP server, the CodeIgniter code works.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

If I switch to GET as form method instead of POST, the values are submitted and accessible in the controller and view. However, I don't want to submit the password as URL parameter. 
Why is post not working on AWS EC2 but on local MAMP server?

Answer (score 0):

Please use `base_url()` instead of `site_url()`. You can try to `echo base_url()` as a way of troubleshooting.

```html
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/auth/index" name="login_form" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    Email: <input name="user_email" id="user_email" value="" />
    <br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="user_password" id="user_password" value="" />
<br>
    <input type="submit" name="login_submit" id="login_submit" />
</form>
```

Editted.

Your controller should looc something like this

```html
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

 public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        // Your own constructor code
    }
    
    function login(){
     $data['message'] = 'Your message';
     $this->load->view('login', $data);
    }

    function login_test(){
        echo $this->input->post('user_email');
    }
}
```

Your view

```html
<?php echo '<h3>'. $message . '</h3>'?>
<span style="color: red;"><?php echo validation_errors(); ?></span>

<form action="<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/login_test" name="login_form" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    Email: <input name="user_email" id="user_email" value="" />
    <br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="user_password" id="user_password" value="" />
<br>
    <input type="submit" name="login_submit" id="login_submit" />
</form>
```

This should `echo` out the email address.

Comment: using `<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/auth/index" name="login_form" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">` does not help.

Comment: Please provide the controller code. We use `$this->input->post('user_email');` to `echo` out the post.

Comment: `var_dump($this->input->post('user_email'))` displays null